# Can't bake high poly normals to low poly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, baking, normal-map, retopology

I'm trying to bake the hole and beveled edges of the high poly, but the bake results in either a blank map or a blank map with holes where the UV is. I've tried selecting the high poly first and then the low, setting color space to non-color, adding a cage, tweaking the ray distance and extrusion, matching the high and low poly UVs and shrinkwrapping the low poly. Both are exactly in the same place with rotation and scale applied.

high:[image: high poly]

low:[image: low poly]

normal map i get:[image: baked normal map]

Comment: Hello, please share your object: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: like this? https://pasteall.org/blend/432fc1f701294c3ab5222e931c668df8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give visibility back to the high-poly object (I didn't know it was important for baking the normals). Also, increase a bit the *Extrusion* value in the *Bake* panel (something like 0.1).

[image]

Comment: This fixed it! Than you so much for the help!

Comment: Although the normals look a little flat, is there a trick to make them look deeper or is this just a limitation when working with normal maps?

Comment: This is a limitation, baking the normals will save the faces orientation, not the depth, it can fake 3D but it is not real 3D